# access variable from outside loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, variables

I know that this is fundamental JS, but I'd like a simple explanation. From what I've read, If i declare an empty variable outside of my loop, the variable inside the loop should be accessible globally? Or am I totally wrong?

I would like to access `randAd` from outside my `for` loop.

```
var mobileAds = [
    "mobile/bb.jpg",
    "mobile/eyeko.jpg",
    "mobile/farfetch.jpg",
    "mobile/fsb.jpg"
];

var randNum = (Math.floor(Math.random() * mobileAds.length));
var randAd;

var i;
for (i = 0; i < mobileAds.length; ++i) {
    randAd = (mobileAds[randNum]);
}
```

Comment: Duh. Thanks @adiga

Comment: The answer you have marked as accepted creates an array with the same `ad` repeated 4 times. Did you intend to create an array or a single string variable in `randAd`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to access every element of `randAd` outside the `for` loop try like this `var randAd = [];` to initialize it as an array. You can easily access it after your for loop but If you use it as a simple variable `var randAd;`then you'll get the last variable always (it overwrites). So initialize it as an array and push every element inside loop before outputting it.

```js
var mobileAds = [
        "mobile/bb.jpg",
        "mobile/eyeko.jpg",
        "mobile/farfetch.jpg",
        "mobile/fsb.jpg"
    ];
    
var randNum = (Math.floor(Math.random() * mobileAds.length));
var randAd = []; // see the change here
    
var i;
for (i = 0; i < mobileAds.length; ++i) {
    randAd.push(mobileAds[randNum]); // push every element here
}
console.log(randAd);
```

Comment: Thank you! `push` makes sense when storing an `array`. But originally I was just trying to access a simple variable from outside a `function`. Is my code correct in that instance?

Comment: Yeah it seems Ok.

Answer (score 3):

You are overthinking. You have done the hard bit in getting a random number between 0 and array's length. So, just get the `ad` at that index:

```
var randAd = mobileAds[randNum];
```

No need to use `for` loop at all.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to use randAd it should be initialised as an empty array `[]` and then push in that array from inside your loop `randAd.push()`. Like this:

```
var randAd=[];

var i;
for (i = 0; i < mobileAds.length; ++i) {
    randAd.push(mobileAds[randNum]);
}
```